# Array of String и Access violation (Delphi)

Tags: массивы, delphi

Использую обычный строковый массив.
Объявляю:

```
var
  html_table_code : array of String;
```

Далее пытаюсь его использовать, внести в него данные.

```
  html_table_code[0] := 'простое текстовое значение';
```

И тут выскакивает `Access violation at address...`
Что-то забыл ещё указать?

Comment: @nick_n_a, в Delphi тоже можно, но вопрос - зачем?

Comment: @nick_n_a, я Delphi-то учил лет 12 назад, лет 7 как в нём особо ни чего не программирую, а вы хотите, что бы я ради одного отчёта в HTML, изучил целый другой язык программирования C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы забыли выделить память под элементы массива. Например так:

```
SetLength(html_table_code, 100); // теперь можно обращаться к 0-99 элементу
```

Comment: Открыл старинные свои исходники и тоже увидел, что сталкивался с этой проблемой и в те времена переходил на более универсальный TStringList. Но про выделение памяти под обычный строковый массив знать тоже обязательно. Спасибо!

Comment: А если размер массива вам известен заранее, и менять его вы не будете, то можно использовать определение: `html_table_code : array [0..99] of String;`. В отличие от динамики выше, в этом случае вы можете создать массив с любым диапазоном индексов, например [1..100].

Answer (score 2):

Класс `TStringList` вам в помощь. И его методы `Clear`, `Add()` и `Insert()`, а также свойство `Strings` для доступа к элементам по индексам.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TStringList

Comment: Хотел бы плюсануть, но к сожалению, это не ответ на вопрос, а комментарий.

Comment: Открыл старые исходники и понял, что сталкивался с этим очень давно и дабы себя не мучить использовал ещё тогда TStringList! Принял бы ваш ответ как правильный, но ответ @Kromster конкретнее относится именно к возникающей ошибке при использовании строкового массива. И да, получается ещё там, для количества элементов, надо динамику прикручивать. А StringList уже весь сконструирован под эти нужды.